# Guitar - Should I Learn the Major Scale Patterns?

Tags: technique, scales, solos, flamenco

I am already pretty good in using the minor and major pentatonic scales to solo. I also learned CAGED for minor/major chords on the fret-board. The issue is, I am struggling to make meaningful music when chord-chasing because of the limited possibilities the pentatonic patterns offer. I love the way [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CLJHX5yaumA) sounds but it seems like he's using a lot more notes than are in the pentatonic patterns to achieve that "flamenco" style.

I guess my real question is, is it necessary to learn the full major/minor patterns on the fret-board to advance playing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing pents is a great start, so you know 5 out of the 7 notes needed to finish off your major and minor scale patterens. Find those extra couple of notes - they're the 2nd and 6th notes in minor, and 4th and 7th in major. Actually the same pair of notes if you consider relatives - as in Am/C maj.

They are the 'iffy' notes that are often left out of solos, as they can clash quite badly (well?) if care isn't taken as to where they sit in a solo line. But, without them, you're missing an important part of your armoury.

So, yes, of course, any more knowledge has to be a good thing, so get them under your fingers, one pattern at a time, using the pent patterns as and when you can as guides.

Then consider modes, blues scales, etc. Even, for fun, try to make up your own scales. You probably won't find one that hasn't already been named, but it'll hone your concepts of how notes can (or won't) fit with each other in given circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is opinion based, however my opinion is that any musician who does not know their major scales should learn them. Further any musician who knows their major scales but not the minor scales should learn them as well. The pentatonics are also important.

The next level after that is perhaps to learn, and learn to use the modes, and Melodic and harmonic minor scales. Then there is the whole tone scale and the ..... There will always be another scale to learn or another way to look at the scales you know so get to work and learn them and it can only make you better which is another way of saying "take you to the next level".